# My HMaster is invisible after 30 sec. Error

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hive, apache-pig, cloudera

I have hbase-0.94.10 version .. all my setting works fine

**Here is my JPS command output**

11804 HRegionServer

10784 TaskTracker

12401 HQuorumPeer

10539 SecondaryNameNode

10201 NameNode

10369 DataNode

12669 JPS

10619 JobTracker

11624 HMaster

**But after 30 sec. passed and if i type JPS command again then output was -**

11804 HRegionServer

10784 TaskTracker

12401 HQuorumPeer

10539 SecondaryNameNode

10201 NameNode

10369 DataNode

12669 JPS

10619 JobTracker

**Looks like HMaster is missing** and because of this i am not able to access hbase master-status on web browser

Anyhelp please ..

Thanks

Comment: Please check the logs for these type of problems!

Comment: Same with me I have collected the errors and exceptions from logs here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314431/errors-trying-to-run-hbase-in-pseudodistributed-mode

Answer (score 0):

One of the issue could be stale zookeeper data. Try to remove zookeeper data and restart HBase.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the logs.

Run HBase at debug level and try starting the master.  Search for Exception.