# Errors - trying to run hbase in pseudodistributed mode?

Tags: exception, hadoop, hbase

I have the following errors while trying to run hbase in pseudodistributed mode

```
Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase/backup-masters/VirtualBox,43390,137692277602
Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /hbase/online-snapshot/acquired 
Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase/online-snapshot
Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase/root-region-server
Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase/table92/-ROOT-2013-08-19 16:38:34,281 WARN
```

and following exceptions

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException
org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn:caught end of stream exception
```

Hbase-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:54310/hbase</value>
        </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>localhost</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.distributed</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

The hbase-env.sh looks like

```
#
#/**
# * Copyright 2007 The Apache Software Foundation
# *
# * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# * distributed with this work for additional information
# * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
# *
# *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
# *
# * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# * limitations under the License.
# */

# Set environment variables here.

# This script sets variables multiple times over the course of starting an hbase process,
# so try to keep things idempotent unless you want to take an even deeper look
# into the startup scripts (bin/hbase, etc.)

# The java implementation to use.  Java 1.6 required.
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25

# Extra Java CLASSPATH elements.  Optional.
#export HBASE_CLASSPATH=/home/hduser/Desktop/hbase-0.94.10

# The maximum amount of heap to use, in MB. Default is 1000.
export HBASE_HEAPSIZE=400

# Extra Java runtime options.
# Below are what we set by default.  May only work with SUN JVM.
# For more on why as well as other possible settings,
# see http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/PerformanceTuning
export HBASE_OPTS="-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"

# Uncomment one of the below three options to enable java garbage collection logging for the server-side processes.

# This enables basic gc logging to the .out file.
# export SERVER_GC_OPTS="-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps"

# This enables basic gc logging to its own file.
# If FILE-PATH is not replaced, the log file(.gc) would still be generated in the HBASE_LOG_DIR .
# export SERVER_GC_OPTS="-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:<FILE-PATH>"

# This enables basic GC logging to its own file with automatic log rolling. Only applies to jdk 1.6.0_34+ and 1.7.0_2+.
# If FILE-PATH is not replaced, the log file(.gc) would still be generated in the HBASE_LOG_DIR .
# export SERVER_GC_OPTS="-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:<FILE-PATH> -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=1 -XX:GCLogFileSize=512M"

# Uncomment one of the below three options to enable java garbage collection logging for the client processes.

# This enables basic gc logging to the .out file.
# export CLIENT_GC_OPTS="-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps"

# This enables basic gc logging to its own file.
# If FILE-PATH is not replaced, the log file(.gc) would still be generated in the HBASE_LOG_DIR .
# export CLIENT_GC_OPTS="-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:<FILE-PATH>"

# This enables basic GC logging to its own file with automatic log rolling. Only applies to jdk 1.6.0_34+ and 1.7.0_2+.
# If FILE-PATH is not replaced, the log file(.gc) would still be generated in the HBASE_LOG_DIR .
# export CLIENT_GC_OPTS="-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:<FILE-PATH> -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=1 -XX:GCLogFileSize=512M"

# Uncomment below if you intend to use the EXPERIMENTAL off heap cache.
# export HBASE_OPTS="$HBASE_OPTS -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize="
# Set hbase.offheapcache.percentage in hbase-site.xml to a nonzero value.


# Uncomment and adjust to enable JMX exporting
# See jmxremote.password and jmxremote.access in $JRE_HOME/lib/management to configure remote password access.
# More details at: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html
#
# export HBASE_JMX_BASE="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
# export HBASE_MASTER_OPTS="$HBASE_MASTER_OPTS $HBASE_JMX_BASE -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10101"
# export HBASE_REGIONSERVER_OPTS="$HBASE_REGIONSERVER_OPTS $HBASE_JMX_BASE -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10102"
# export HBASE_THRIFT_OPTS="$HBASE_THRIFT_OPTS $HBASE_JMX_BASE -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10103"
# export HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_OPTS="$HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_OPTS $HBASE_JMX_BASE -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10104"

# File naming hosts on which HRegionServers will run.  $HBASE_HOME/conf/regionservers by default.
export HBASE_REGIONSERVERS=/home/hduser/Desktop/hbase-0.94.10/conf/regionservers

# File naming hosts on which backup HMaster will run.  $HBASE_HOME/conf/backup-masters by default.
# export HBASE_BACKUP_MASTERS=${HBASE_HOME}/conf/backup-masters

# Extra ssh options.  Empty by default.
# export HBASE_SSH_OPTS="-o ConnectTimeout=1 -o SendEnv=HBASE_CONF_DIR"

# Where log files are stored.  $HBASE_HOME/logs by default.
export HBASE_LOG_DIR=/home/hduser/Desktop/hbase-0.94.10/logs

# Enable remote JDWP debugging of major HBase processes. Meant for Core Developers 
# export HBASE_MASTER_OPTS="$HBASE_MASTER_OPTS -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8070"
# export HBASE_REGIONSERVER_OPTS="$HBASE_REGIONSERVER_OPTS -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8071"
# export HBASE_THRIFT_OPTS="$HBASE_THRIFT_OPTS -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8072"
# export HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_OPTS="$HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_OPTS -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8073"

# A string representing this instance of hbase. $USER by default.
# export HBASE_IDENT_STRING=$USER

# The scheduling priority for daemon processes.  See 'man nice'.
# export HBASE_NICENESS=10

# The directory where pid files are stored. /tmp by default.
export HBASE_PID_DIR=/home/hduser/Desktop/hbase-0.94.10/pids

# Seconds to sleep between slave commands.  Unset by default.  This
# can be useful in large clusters, where, e.g., slave rsyncs can
# otherwise arrive faster than the master can service them.
# export HBASE_SLAVE_SLEEP=0.1

# Tell HBase whether it should manage it's own instance of Zookeeper or not.
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
```

My /etc/hosts has the following content

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
127.0.1.1       VirtualBox
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
#::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
#fe00::0 ip6-localnet
#ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
#ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
#ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Answer (score 0):

in your /etc/hosts what configuration you have

make

127.0.1.1 localhost on HBase client

Because of this ip's you are facing this problem. 127.0.0.1    127.0.1.1

try to configure real ip with proper gateway, submask number etc in(Ubuntu) /etc/network/interfaces file

Comment: i tried adjusting the ip of VirtualBox to 10.0.2.15 after finding it via `ifconfig` command but it did not work ...

Comment: could you please try to ping 10.0.2.15 ip from windows cmd - just type 'ping 10.0.2.15' on cmd. if it shows request time out then you are configured wrong IP for your virtual box . . !

Comment: No the ip is fine ,i have solved the problem by re installing hbase